# Angular evaluate variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following loop:

```
$scope.loop = ['loopone','looptwo'];

$scope.loopone = {'one', 'two'};
$scope.looptwo = {'three', 'four'};
```

and I'm looping through it here:

```
<div ng-repeat="slug in loop">
  <div ng-repeat="val in {{ slug }}">{{ val }}</div>
</div>
```

How do I evaluate the `{{ slug }}` inside the second `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Your edit completely changed your question.

Comment: Are `$scope.loopone` and `$scope.looptwo` supposed to be arrays?  Those aren't valid objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript's [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access a property with the key name.  You could bind to the result of a controller function to grab the correct array.  So your markup could look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="slug in loop">
  Slug: {{slug}}
  <div ng-repeat="val in getValuesFromSlug(slug)">{{ val }}</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$scope.getValuesFromSlug = function (slug) {
    return $scope[slug];
}
```

[Demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HHvV6EzkJidv2ycm086y?p=preview)

Comment: Would it not be cleaner to use the index?
`<div ng-repeat="val in {{ slug[$index] }}">{{ val }}</div>`

Comment: @MattLishman yes `$index` is very useful.  I'm not entirely sure what state the OP's code is currently in.

Comment: @MattLishman No need for the curly braces around slug. The `ng-repeat` iterator knows what state it's currently on.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Good point. I just copied the code that was already there and replaced it with $index.

Answer (score 0):

Use can angular evaluate `$eval()` method and it will resolve your problem

```
<div ng-repeat="slug in loop">
  <div ng-repeat="val in $eval(slug)">{{ val }}</div>
</div>
```

As @ryanyuyu mentioned, `$scope.loopone` and `$scope.looptwo` should be array

```
$scope.loopone = ['one', 'two'];
$scope.looptwo = ['three', 'four'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have a tree structure in your view, it'd be easiest to have it be a tree in your controller as well.

Example:

In controller:

```
$scope.loops = [
    [1,2,3], [4,5,6]
];
```

In view:

```
<div ng-repeat="miniloop in loop">
  <div ng-repeat="val in miniloop">{{ val }}</div>
</div>
```

This is extremely easy to iterate through, and you can push and remove elements from either depth with ease (which will immediately be reflected in the view).

The way you were doing it, trying to use constant variables as if they were dynamically created, will lead you down a path of spaghetti code and unscalability.